# Detect current input language

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, nssearchfield

I am building an app which allows users to check the local time in any place around the world. The information is being fetched using Google APIs and all works well, but for the best results I need to specify the language which I would like to use.

Obviously, in my case, it makes sense to set the desired language to the one which user used when typing a city name. On iPhone this is super easy to do, but I cannot figure out how I could get this language code on macOS. Could anyone help me please?

**Update**

Following an advice from Leo I am now at the stage when I am getting the current input with the help of carbon framework.

```
let source = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource().takeUnretainedValue()
let lang = TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyInputSourceLanguages).assumingMemoryBound(to: NSArray.self).pointee
```

The problem is that `TISGetInputSourceProperty()` returns an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`. And I cannot find a way to convert it to something readable. I assume it is an `NSArray`, but I have no luck trying to convert it. Can someone help please?

Comment: Do you want to know the prefered language in the Language and Region preferences?

Comment: The property is CFString.

Answer (score 1):

```
let source = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource().takeUnretainedValue()
let value = TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyInputSourceLanguages)
if (value != nil) {
    var name = Unmanaged<AnyObject>.fromOpaque(value!).takeUnretainedValue() as? String
}
```

I learn it form here https://github.com/noraesae/kawa/blob/master/kawa/InputSourceManager.swift

Answer (score 0):

Carbon has `TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource()` which gives you the current language.

TISInputSourceRef source = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource();
TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyInputSourceLanguages));

There is also the `kTISNotifySelectedKeyboardInputSourceChanged` distributed notification to determine when language changes.

For Swift ease of use, consider making an Objective C wrapper which returns a string value of the above API.

Comment: No, this doesn't work. If I type "Paris" or "Hello" it displays "und" as a language. It really would be better to just get access to the current input language of the keyboard.... For long string your solution works, but in my case users are going to search for cities, so only short name will be typed.

Comment: Carbon has `TISCopyCurrentKeyboardInputSource` which gives you the current language. There is also the `kTISNotifySelectedKeyboardInputSourceChanged` distributed notification to determine when language changes.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this method and it looks like it is working. However, it returns UnsafeMutableRawPointer and I cannot find a way to properly read it. You can check my updated answer

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk I suggest using a ObjC wrapper around the API in question. Will be much easier.